# Codename One WebSocket code failed to connect to the server

Tags: codenameone

This is my first time to use Websocket. I wrote a simple test code (with the Websocket CN1LIB : https://github.com/shannah/cn1-websockets) but it doesn’t work. Can you tell me what is wrong with my code please? 
I wrote the websocket server code in go (golang) and when I make a test with a client code that i wrote in HTML/JavaScript in the browser, it works very well. With the codename one code, it fails to connect to the server.

```
 WebSocket sock=new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8080/ws") {
        @Override
        protected void onOpen() {
            System.out.println("Connexion établie");
        }

    @Override
    protected void onClose(int statusCode, String reason) {
        System.out.println("Fin de connexion");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMessage(String message) {
        System.out.println("Réponse reçue du serveur - version string : "+message);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMessage(byte[] message) {
        System.out.println("Réponse reçue du serveur (version byte[]): "+message);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onError(Exception ex) {
        System.out.println("Une erreur s'est produite: "+ex.getMessage());
    }
};

sock.autoReconnect(5000);

if(sock==null){
    System.out.println("Le socket est nul");
}

Form f = new Form("Hi World", BoxLayout.y());
msg_recu=new Label();
msg=new TextField();
Button envoyer=new Button("Envoyer");
envoyer.addActionListener(evt->{
    sock.connect();
    sock.send(msg.getText());
});

f.addAll(msg_recu, msg, envoyer);

f.show();
```

When I run this code, it show me the error message of the **onError** method.
**Une erreur s'est produite: Exception occurred while trying to connect.**
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is almost right but you made one tiny mistake which I made as well the first time I used websockets. Change this:

```
envoyer.addActionListener(evt->{
    sock.connect();
    sock.send(msg.getText());
});
```

To remove the send call:

```
envoyer.addActionListener(evt-> sock.send(msg.getText()));
```

The send call should be done only when the connection is established otherwise it won't work:

```
    @Override
    protected void onOpen() {
        System.out.println("Connexion établie");
        send(msg.getText());
    }
```